# Static library of libcurl on windows

Tags: c++, c, gcc, libcurl, static-linking

How to link this library libcurl statically to the exe? i have tried

--disable-share --enable-static that does not help.

I am using MingW32

Is there an easy way to statically link this library so i can have no more .dlls with my app?

Comment: This is for Visual Studio. Not for mingw my friend.

Comment: Whether you use Visual Studio or not won't make a big difference. The concept is the same.

Answer (score 2):

If using codeblocks, right click your project and press properties then on the defines tab, add:

`CURL_STATICLIB`

if using command line then:

`-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -lcurl -lws2_32 -lwinmm`

Comment: If i use this command i get tons of 'undefined reference' to api's in libcurl.a

Comment: I've tried to include `CURL_STATICLIB` in **Preprocessor Definitions**, but it doesn't work. It still requires the libcurl.dll

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -static in linker options

Comment: I tried this option but it will not let me compile i get these errors                  clns.c:(.text+0xad7e): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_e
asy_init'
clns.c:(.text+0xb1d6): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_e
asy_cleanup'
clns.c:(.text+0xb6bb): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_e
asy_cleanup'
clns.c:(.text+0xbc71): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_e
asy_cleanup'
clns.c:(.text+0xc3bc): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_e
asy_init'

Comment: @amaninlove, you need -lcurl also and you need to define curl library path.

Comment: How i can specify the path? isn't setting up a PATH in the environment variable enough?

Comment: Sorry i mean i have copied the lib files of libcurl to Mingw lib directory so specifying the path isn't the problem.I have specified already your command -lcurl still getting the same issue with even more undefined reference like `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libcurl.a(md5.o):(.text+0x15): undefined reference to MD5_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libcurl.a(md5.o)`
. But if i specify the option `-lcurldll` only then it compiles fine but the dll still there not statically linked.

Comment: @amaninlove: gcc -DCURL_STATICLIB -I ../../include -L ../../lib simple.c -o simple -lcurl -lws2_32 -lwinmm

Comment: Thanks i got rid of all errors but still not staticaly linked the `libcurl.dll` is still there, now the problem is there is more dependencies. I can see my app now relying on many .dll files like `zlib1.dll` `LIBEAY32.dll` `libidn-11.dll` `SSLEAY32.dll` `wldap32.dll` What i am doing wrong here? i have also disabled the use of SSL but it still imports them, moreover i am seeing those functions like `curl_easy_cleanup` etc are now turned inside export directory.

Comment: And here is the command-line i am using  `CFLAGS="-O2 -static -DCURL_STATICLIB -DHTTP_ONLY -lcurl -lcurldll -lrtmp -lcrypto -lidn -lssl -lws2_32 -lwinmm -Izlib -lwldap32 -lz -leay32 -lpthread -msse2" ./configure`

Comment: no ideas, see: http://fatchoco.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/using-curl-in-mingw/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps how to do that. but you may get some additional errors. those are need to figure out by yourself. This is Just a guidance.

1. You should have two project in Visual Studio Solution

   - libcurl project (source code downloaded from curl web. [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf) may help you for this)
   - your project
2. Build libcurl as a static lib.(right click `libcurl project` in solution explorer -> properties -> configuration properties -> General-> change `configuration Type` to `Static Library (.lib)`)
3. Then right click your project go to propertied ->configuration properties ->Linker -> general
4. In "additional Library directories" add the path to above curl.lib.
5. then  go to propertied ->configuration properties ->Linker -> input
6. add libcurl.lib name to `additional dependencies`.
7. then go to properties -> configuration properties -> General
8. If your project uses MFC or ATL change `use of MFC` and `use of ATL` to `use MFC in static library` and `use ATL in static library` accordingly.
9. then build the solution.
10. Enjoy libcurl :)